# Vim get length of matched line

Tags: regex, vim

I am trying to use vim substitute commands to transform type specific C-code into macro Code. This example snippet

```
#define LIST_GEN_FUNCS(TYPE)
struct list_##TYPE* list_generate() {  
struct list_##TYPE* ret = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
ret->len = 0; ret->first = 0;
return ret;
}
```

needs to look like that:

```
#define LIST_GEN_FUNCS(TYPE)                               
struct list_##TYPE* list_generate() {                     \
struct list_##TYPE* ret = malloc(sizeof(struct list));    \
ret->len = 0; ret->first = 0;                             \
return ret;                                               \
}                                                         \
```

To do this, i need a way to fill up all columns with whitespaces until a fixed line length, then add '\' after each line ending.

```
%s/$/\= submatch(0) . " " . repeat(" ", 78 - LENGTH_OF_LINE)
```

Now, here is my problem. I was not able to find out how to get the length of a matched line. Could anyone tell me, what to insert as LENGTH_OF_LINE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to add spaces to the end of the line and then delete to a specific column. For example:

```
:%norm80A <C-v><Esc>d80|s\<cr>
```

The `<C-v><Esc>` inserts a literal `^[` character and the `<cr>` ends the command.

If you want to find the length of a line in VimL you can use `strlen(getline(6))` for example if you wanted to get the length of line 6. If you wanted to implement that into your existing solution you could do

```
:%s/$/\=repeat(" ", 79-strlen(getline(".")))."\\"
```

As Zyx says in the comments, a better way is

```
:%s/$/\=repeat(" ", 80-virtcol("$"))."\\"
```

Comment: `virtcol('$')-1` is far better choice then `strlen(getline('.'))` as it respects both tabs and unicode characters.

Answer (score 1):

My [AlignFromCursor plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4155) lets you align the text right of the cursor to a particular column, either via a command or mapping. This way, you could just append the backslash and then align it afterwards.